# How to add a redirect after form submission?

Tags: html, redirect, button

How to add a redirect after form submission?

Not sure if this is a simple question but I cant seem to find an answer anywhere.

```
<form id="mlgkush">
  <input id="Email" 
    name="Email" 
    type="email" 
    placeholder="Email" 
    value="" 
    spellcheck="false" 
    class="">

  <input id="Passwd" name="Passwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="">
</form>

<input id="signIn" 
  name="signIn" 
  class="rc-button rc-button-submit" 
  type="submit"
  value="Sign in">
```

Comment: Form inputs normally go inside a form tag where you specify the target URL and the method, GET or POST   Please see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: You need some kind of server-side program (PHP, ASP, Python, Perl, etc.) to receive the form submission and respond with a HTTP redirect.

Comment: All `<input>` elements should be inside the `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this you want to do???**

**Updated!!!**(after you edit your question)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="mlgkush" action="action_page.php">
  
Email:<br>
 <input id="Email" name="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email" value="" spellcheck="false" class="">
<br>

Password:<br>
 <input id="Passwd" name="Passwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" class=""><br><br>

    <input id="signIn" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Sign in" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the button to be multi functional, in short I want it to submit the login then redirect to a website.

Comment: check my solution now,which is act as a multi functional,and please be noted you must need to put submit button within a form tag,without doing it,form is not submit,

Comment: My apologies if I was not specific enough, the forum I have currently records the login data. What I am looking for is that once the data is sent, you are redirected. For example; back to the homepage.